# insert form data into one table, then insert specific form data in to table 2 and update enum value?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to insert my form data into my table 'supplier_registration', however this is not working, i am getting mysql 'ERROR', I am not sure why this is happening.

I am also wanting to insert the same form data into a second table 'supplier_session', but this time only inserting specific bits of the form data, '$cname' and '$creg'.

When a user lands on the page there ip address is inserted into the table 'supplier_session' so when this form is submitted i also want the supplier_session table to update an enum value 'form1_complete' from no to yes, where that user's ip or 'user_IP' exists in the table row. i am trying to d this by running three querys but its not working, please can someone show me where i am going wrong. Thanks

Database:

```
ID(AI) | company_name | company_reg_number | company_incorp_date | company_address | company_postcode | contact_name | contact_number | contact_email | company_vat_number | date_time | user_IP
```

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'hewden1'; 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)    
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)   
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

 $cname       = $_POST['cname'];
   $creg      = $_POST['creg'];  
   $address      = $_POST['address'];  
   $post      = $_POST['post'];  
   $contactn      = $_POST['contactn'];
   $contactt      = $_POST['contactt'];
  $contacte      = $_POST['contacte'];
   $vat     = $_POST['vat'];
    $incorp      = $_POST['incorp'];

    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];




$sql="INSERT INTO supplier_registration (company_name, company_reg_number, company_incorp_date, company_address, company_postcode, contact_name, contact_number, contact_email, company_vat_number, date_time, user_ip)
    VALUES ('$cname', '$creg', '$incorp', $address', '$post', '$contactn', '$contactt', '$contacte', '$vat', NOW(), '$ipaddress')";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 


$qry2 = "INSERT INTO supplier_session (company_reg_number, company_name) VALUES('$creg','$cname') WHERE user_IP = '$ipaddress'";

 $result = @mysql_query($qry2);

$qry3="UPDATE supplier_session SET form1_completed = 'Yes' WHERE form1_completed = 'No' AND user_IP = '$ipaddress'";

$result = mysql_query($q); 



if($result){

header("Location: index.php?registration=sucess");


}else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

html:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myform" action="company_info_process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<input type="text" id="field_cname" name="cname" class="field_cname">

<input type='text' name='creg' id="field_creg">

<input type='text' name='incorp' id="field_incorp">

<input type='text' name='vat' id="field_vat">

<input type='text' name='contactn' id="field_contactn">

<input type="text" name="contactt" id="field_contactt">

<input type="text" id="field_contacte" name="contacte">

<input type="text" id="field_address" name="address">

<input type="text" id="field_post" name="post"/>
```

Comment: "i am getting mysql 'ERROR'" Post the specific error in your question.

Comment: You can't use a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement. `INSERT` is for adding new rows, not modifying existing rows, so how would the `WHERE` clause be used?

Comment: that is the ERROR, mysql either executes or echo's out error

Comment: Your script is echoing `ERROR`. You should get the actual error message from MySQL with `echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: Before you go any further, you should really learn about [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Simple, change `$result = mysql_query($q);` to `$result = mysql_query($qry3);` @JohnTaylor There's your error. However, using the same variable `$result = mysql_query` for all your queries may also contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly,* you are calling the wrong variable in your third query.

Change `$result = mysql_query($q);` to `$result = mysql_query($qry3);`

Also, with the [`INSERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) syntax, you cannot have a [`WHERE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html) clause. The only time you will find `INSERT` that has a `WHERE` clause is when you are using an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

*Besides that,* the `WHERE` clause is mostly used when doing a [`SELECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) or [`UPDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

*Quick sidenote:* I noticed you don't have a closing `</form>` tag. If that is your actual code, add it.

Use error reporting at the top of your page(s):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Plus, use:

```
else{
    echo mysql_errno($db_server) . ": " . mysql_error($db_server) . "\n";
    }
```

Instead of:

```
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Visit PHP.net for more information on error reporting.

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php**

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score -1):

Where you run your call to `mysql_query`, output any error messages it generates:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Should give some indication of which query is causing the error and why.

Edit: Also, Noticed you have a `WHERE` clause within an `INSERT` statement, you can't do that.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Comments don't have adequate formatting options for showing how to capture that error message. I also went ahead and added a possible reason for the error.